# PHP namespaces and using the \ prefix in declaration

Tags: php, namespaces

The following throws an error stating `Exception` can not be redeclared.

```
namespace \NYTD\ReadingListBackend;

class Exception extends \Exception
{
}
```

However, removing the `\` prefix in the namespace declaration does not:

```
namespace NYTD\ReadingListBackend;
```

I recently adopted PHP namespaces. My understanding is that namespaces prefixed with `\` represent a *fully qualified name*.

So why can't I use the prefix in the namespace declaration? I can when referencing (e.g. `new \NYTD\ReadingListBackend\Exception`). Would appreciate a full explanation as I couldn't find anything in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Comment: In the docs they use the \ at beginning only to call it. To declare it they dont't use it. So it should be: namespace NYTD\ReadingListBackend; and when you want to access it, you only write NYTD\ReadingListBackend\Exception;

Comment: I think PHP expects `\NYTD\ReadingListBackend` to be a constant or something. Omit the initial `\` and you should be fine

Comment: @PKeidel, can you supply a link. I must have missed that line of the docs.

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem, I realize that. I'm trying to understand the internals of *why*.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php

Comment: @JasonMcCreary it doesnt say. I am just applying Occam's Razor, which means the likelihood of the manual showing the correct usage is higher than the theory that it is missing that you can apply the backslash. But you have a look at http://lxr.php.net/search?q=T_NAMESPACE&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=PHP_TRUNK - the truth is in there.

Comment: @Jason I only looked at the examples. E.g. [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php#104136) or [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php)

Comment: @Gordon, understood. Honestly, I don't mean to be difficult. I realize the \ prefix in the namespace declaration *doesn't work*. I'm just trying to understand *why*.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I didnt perceive you to be difficult at all. My C is just not good enough to explain "*why*" at the level you are likely looking for in an answer, hence the link to the source.

Comment: @Gordon, the way I read the grammar, a prefix of `T_NS_SEPARATOR` is allowed. So the question becomes, why do the two namespace declarations parse differently…

Comment: The prefix *does not work* with curly brackets notation ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IJyVXN)). I'd say when this was implemented, it was not possible to throw a parse error in the case you outline because of the limited abilities of the PHP parser (or was too hard to create and then just dropped).

Comment: @hakre, thanks for the example. What does that mean as far as an answer?

Comment: No, it does not answer the question at all, it adds more question marks I'd say ;) Interesting find by the way!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers the `namespace` declaration always takes a fully-qualified name and as such a trailing `\` would be redundant and is not allowed.

Writing `namespace \NYTD\ReadingListBackend { ... }` will lead to a proper parse error.

When using the semicolon notation `namespace \NYTD\ReadingListBackend;` on the other hand it is interpreted as `namespace\NYTD\ReadingListBackend;`, which is an access to the constant `NYTD\ReadingListBackend` (the `namespace` keyword here resolves to the currently active namespace, which in your case is the global one).

So your code does not declare any namespace (it is global) and just tries to access a constant. That's why you end up redefining `Exception`.

By the way, the reason why the undefined constant access does not throw a fatal error is class hoisting. Your class declaration is evaluated first, so PHP never actually reaches the constant access (even though it comes first in code).

Comment: +1 Excellent explanation. But if this is true, then that would mean the grammar allows for spaces in namespaces. Which seems wrong.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Correct. PHP ignores all whitespace and comments. It does not care whether you write `namespace\Foo\Bar`, `namespace \ Foo \ Bar` or `namespace /* a */ \ /* very */ Foo /* odd */ \ /* comment */ Bar` ;)

Comment: Yes, but it should not ignore whitespace in this case. It doesn't for  `$ var`. Nonetheless, I verified your answer by using `echo __NAMESPACE__;` after the declaration. This is indeed what happens with the \ prefix.

Answer (score 2):

> So why can't I use the prefix in the namespace declaration?

By definition when you declare a namespace name it *is* already fully qualified.

But inside a namespace'd part of the code, if you need to specify a fully qualified class name (FQCN) you need the prefix to signal PHP that the *class* name is a FQCN.

What is irritating here is that PHP does not already error out at parse time in your example. I can not tell you why.

```
namespace \NYTD\ReadingListBackend;
          ^- this seems wrong but no parse error
```

However PHP does the error with the curly notation (multiple namespaces in one file):

```
namespace \NYTD\ReadingListBackend {}
                                   ^- parse error in this line
```

But for your question, I think it's worth to differ between the namespace-name and the class-name.

Comment: +1, best answer so far *by definition when you declare a namespace name it is already fully qualified.* :)

Comment: Yes, if you look into http://php.net/language.namespaces.nested you can see that the separator is used only between the namespace names. In http://php.net/language.namespaces.definition no separator is used at all.

Comment: I have read through the docs several times. Without a parse error, I was trying to find something *explicit* about using the separator as a prefix. The fact that it runs, but is interpreted differently ultimately lead to my confusion.

Comment: Yes I can understand the confusion. However, nowhere in the documentation of the `namespace` keyword it is said to use the namespace separator in front of the first name. There is nothing to separate at that place. I think I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Can neither confirm nor deny. I was reluctant to say *bug*. However, after reviewing the grammar, there may be one. Especially given the inconsistency when using namespace block syntax (i.e. `{`).

Answer (score 1):

A `\` prefix means 'root' or something like that. It makes a *fully qualified namespace* (`/Foo/Bar`) of a *qualified namespace* (`Foo/Bar`). This is only useful when using namespaces, not when declaring namespaces. For instance:

```
namespace Foo

class Bar {
    // ...
}

namespace Bar\Baz;

$b = new Bar(); // look for Bar\Baz\Bar()
$b = new Foo\Bar(); // look for Bar\Baz\Foo\Bar()
$b = new \Foo\Bar(); // look for Foo\Bar() (the right one)
```

It isn't usefull when declaring a namespace, because you always declare a namespace from the global ('root') namespace:

```
namespace Foo; // the \Foo namespace
// ...
namespace Bar; // the \Bar namespace, not the \Foo\Bar namespace
// ...
namespace Foo\Bar; // the \Foo\Bar namespace
```

Because every namespace declaration is sort of 'fully qualified' PHP doesn't want a `\` in front of the namespace and gives you an error.

Comment: I read about [namespace resolution](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php). I would expect that using this prefix would either result in a syntax error or work as a *fully qualified namespace*. Not run with a different result…